# Create JIRA issue using Jenkins Jira Step plugin

Tags: jenkins, oauth, jenkins-plugins, jira

Since now basic authentication is disabled in JIRA apis, where I can get these info from.
[image]
I am using this plugin - https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira-steps/

[image]

After @apr_1985 solution getting this -

```
node {
  stage('JIRA') {
    withEnv(['JIRA_SITE=Jira']) {
      def testIssue = [fields: [ project: [key: 'AUT'],
                                 summary: 'SDsad',
                                 issuetype: [name: 'Bug']]]

      response = jiraNewIssue issue: testIssue
      echo response.successful.toString()
      echo response.data.toString()
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Steps to get oauth tokens are in the plugin docs
https://jenkinsci.github.io/jira-steps-plugin/getting-started/config/authentication/
Although looks like basic auth is still available with an API token https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/basic-auth-for-rest-apis/

Comment: thanks man, it solved my issue! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: No worries.  Glad it worked

Comment: @apr_1985 do you have experience with this plugin? I have one more small question

Comment: Sorry I do not.  Feel free to ask though :)

Comment: @apr_1985 I have added one more image that is what I am getting right now - tried couple of things not exactly sure what is the issue